# Does anyone know what the real lyrics are for "Heaven or Las Vegas" by the Cocteau Twins?

Tags: lyrics

There's a song named `Heaven or Las Vegas` by the Cocteau Twins but I'm not what the correct lyrics are.

I've been trying to figure them out for years and could use some good feedback.

Comment: No, just that I've found several differing versions throughout the internet, and the singer, Elizabeth Frasier, uses a singing style called glossalalia which makes it hard to detect what she's actually saying. Sorry if I was not very clear. I'm looking for the most supportable version of the lyrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a search for you on these site:

- [Google Play](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tp5m5wgvuoxdoxvnxwislnrcoca?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics)
- [Genius.com](https://genius.com/Cocteau-twins-heaven-or-las-vegas-lyrics)
- [Lyricsfreak.com](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/c/cocteau+twins/heaven+or+las+vegas_20032499.html)
- [Azlyrics.com](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/cocteautwins/heavenorlasvegas.html)
- [MetroLyrics.com](http://www.metrolyrics.com/heaven-or-las-vegas-lyrics-cocteau-twins.html)

The first two sites are a body different by others.

So I have listen the song on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtBr5JKSuks)

and for me the first two sites are right!

Answer (score 0):

I've read this was a language invented by the author of the lyrics. The real lyrics don't exist, only interpretations of it.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Fraser